# Is there any site where to ask question about Team Foundation Server board?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding the use of Team Foundation Server Board. Since it's not code/programming related I didn't want to ask it in SO.

Is there any site where I can ask these kind of questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions on TFS can be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), since it is a "software tool commonly used by programmers" (third bullet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). If the question is more about maintaining it from a system administrators point-of-view, it can be on-topic on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Be aware that questions how to set up things are too broad quite fast, so be aware that your question is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Questions:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=tfsreporting%2Ctfsgeneral&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc

Suggestions:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Take care,
Dave